# evaluating short to signed short

Tags: binary

Convert the numbers to decimal, assuming we use `signed short`

1. 0b1111111111001000
2. 0b0000000011100010

So we can see that `unsigned short` is 16 bits therefore `signed short` is 8 bits
so for

1.0b1111111111001000 is 11001000 the MSB is 1 and the number is 1001000 so it is -72

2. 0b0000000011100010 is 11100010 the MSB is 1 and the number is 1100010 so it is -196

Or the signed bit is not included in the 8 bits, it is the 9th bit?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. signed short 8 bits??  How can the sign change with the code length? And your conversions are completely incorrect: 2s complement is not a sign-absolute value code. Please clarify the question.

Comment: We cut the number of bit transforming them from unsigned short to signed short

Comment: No, no, no. Signed and unsigned short have exactly the same size 16 bits. The difference is the way bits are interpreted. There are many tutorials. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations